# regression in r with for cycle

Tags: r

I'd like r makes and shows me some regression, the dependent variable shuld be each column of my dataset and the independent variable should be always the same.

```
for (i in 1:50) {

  regressor[i] = lm(data[ , i] ~ data$X__1)
}
```

But r reports the following error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = data[, i] ~ data$X__1,
>   drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :    invalid type (list) for variable
>   'data[, i]'

How can I solve this problem??

Comment: note for `lm` you can pass multiple outcomes in a matrix, instead of using a loop. ie `lm(as.matrix(mtcars[1:10]) ~ carb, mtcars)`

Comment: what is your `data[,i]`? try `is(data[,i])` to get an idea. a simple data frame would consists of atomic vectors of the same length but you can put whatever you want there and it'll still be a data frame. so `data[,i]` can be, e.g., a list of lists, or a list of lists where each sub-list is a length-one vector, or a list of functions, or a matrix ...

Comment: is `regressor` a list? I wonder if using `[[` (instead of `[` here might help. I'd always use `[[` in such cases, i.e. `regressor[[i]] <- something`